# How do I deploy a React Webpack web app to Azure App Service?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, azure-web-app-service

My Azure web app deployment from Dropbox does not work.

I have an App service running. I am trying to deploy my React Webpack app. I have tried deploy from my Bitbucket repo, but that whole project is loaded into D:\home\site\wwwroot and just sits there since Kudu apparently thinks it is a node.js app. From what I've read Kudu does that with any git deployment with a package.json file. So I tried to deploy from Dropbox instead. I set up my app's source correctly to my Dropbox/Apps/Azure/ directory and then clicked Sync. I got the following result:

> Title
>   Synchronization Request Submitted
>   Description
>   The repository for web app  is being updated.
>   Status
>   Informational
>   Timestamp
>   Wed Nov 23 2016 08:44:09 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
>   UTC Timestamp
>   Wed, 23 Nov 2016 13:44:09 GMT
>   Correlation IDs
>   447bf0d0-a533-49dd-898a-57b5be6b5738
>   Percent Completed
>   100

But the bits at D:\home\site\wwwroot still show the code from the old git repo deploys. At my Dropbox page I have the bits that I want to deploy, namely from the build folder after a Webpack build run. They have index.html at the root, so I expect it would be served correctly if just copied over to Azure.

I am quite new at this whole Azure thing, can someone help?

EDITED WITH MORE INFORMATION BELOW.

To be clear, I am not deploying any code like app.js/server.js contained in a wwwroot folder. I have copied only the results from a Webpack build run over to the Dropbox folder that is specified to Azure as the source. That Dropbox folder looks like this:

```
asset-manifest.json
favicon.ico
index.html
splash.css
static
    css
        main.63e4d058.css
        main.63e4d058.css.map
    js
        main.68797484.js
        main.68797484.js.map
    media
        dell-300-426.b435b6bd.png
        duck.1d942aad.svg
        example1.9443ef49.png
        icon_question.3672f035.png
        ipad-montecarlo-demo.2d964854.png
        moneyplan-imac-300-552-new.8814ce0f.png
web.config
```

The index.html file has a script tag with code that points to the main.68797484.js file, which is the bundled app code.

But in Azure Deployment options, after clicking Sync, 
the result reads "No deployments found", even though there was a notification that "The repository for web app is being updated."

Answer (score 4):

I created a repo that should solve this problem with automatic deploys.

https://github.com/ulrikaugustsson/azure-appservice-static

In short it will build the project and then copy the build folder to wwwroot.

Answer (score 3):

Per my experience, if `app.js/server.js` is contained in `wwwroot` floder, then Kudu will think it is a node.js app and generate the `web.config`. So if your app is not node.js app, the `wwwroot` floder should not cover neither app.js nor server.js.

For your reference, I wrote the react & webpack [hello world](https://github.com/achengit/react-hello-word) project and successfully deployed to Azure. Below is the concrete steps, could you please have a try?

1. Put your project to GitHub repo which is similar to Bitbucket. And both of them offer great Git services, here you can use Bitbuket instead.
2. In your app's menu blade in the **Azure portal**, click **APP DEPLOYMENT** > **Deployment options**. Click **Choose Source**, then select the deployment source.
   [image]
3. In the **Deployment source** blade, choose the project and branch to deploy from. When you're done, click **OK**.
   [image]
4. In the Azure portal, click **APP DEPLOYMENT** > **Deployment options**. Then click **Sync** in the blade. [image]
5. Set your entry HTML file in the **Default documents** as below:[image]
6. Eventually, browse your website and you will see something like this:[image]

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but your example doesn't correspond to my case. Please see my edits to my question.